# React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using StackNavigator, inside TabNavigator, inside Drawer Navigator.
Trying to redirect to nested Stacks but returns error.

Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by StackNavigator. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks:

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'prevDeps.length')

What's wront with that?
Why it doesnt redirect to stack.screen below main screen?

my redirect:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.accessButton} onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home', {
        screen: 'Events'
      })}>
```

My main.js (navigator)

```
return (
    <NavigationContainer theme={NavigationTheme} ref={navigationRef}>
      <StatusBar barStyle={darkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'} />
      <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerStyle={{ width: '100%' }}
        drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}
      >
        <Drawer.Screen name="Startup" component={IndexStartupContainer} />
        {isApplicationLoaded && BeforeLogin != null && (
          <Drawer.Screen name="Main" component={BeforeLogin} />
        )}
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
```

my tabbar navigator:

```
return (
    <Tab.Navigator tabBarOptions={{showLabel: false}} lazy>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({size,focused,color}) => {
            return (
              <AntDesign name="home" size={39} color={colors.text} />
            );
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="SearchNavigator" component={SearchNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({size,focused,color}) => {
            return (
              <AntDesign name="search1" size={39} color={colors.text} />
            );
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="FAQNavigator" component={FAQNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({size,focused,color}) => {
            return (
              <AntDesign name="questioncircleo" size={39} color={colors.text} />
            );
          },
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="ContactNavigator" component={ContactNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({size,focused,color}) => {
            return (
              <Feather name="phone" size={39} color={colors.text} />
            );
          },
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
```

and my HomeNavigator:

```
const HomeNavigator = ({ navigation }) => {
  const Stack = createStackNavigator()
  const { t } = useTranslation()
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        options={headerStyle_1}
        name='Index'
        title={t('title.homepage')}
        component={HomepageController}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        options={headerStyle_1}
        name='Events'
        title={t('title.events')}
        component={EventsController}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

Comment: You should not create Stack inside HomeNavigator component. It should be outside the component, otherwise you are just creating a new Stack object on every render.

Comment: sorry, couldnt understand. how can this be possible? how can i put stack navigator, inside tab.navigator component?

Comment: please check the example in react-navigation doc and check where `createStackNavigator()` is called, https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/

Comment: sorry bro, couldnt find difference, seriously. i'm so sad about it. but couldnt understand even I read all docs.

Comment: you are using `const Stack = createStackNavigator()` inside the component, whereas it should be outside the component, but in the same file.